# Dual Linux Images on a single partitioned eMMC for OTA updates on SAMA5D27 ARM based MPU

Tags: arm, microchip, linux, bootloader, emmc

To be able to support OTA updates I want to load the new update image to one partition and have the current running image on the other partition. Then switch partition to run from the new image at next boot, with possibility to switch back if the new image fails to boot. The switching would be managed by the boot loader.

Question: Is it possible to have two bootable images on a single eMMC or would you need to have two separate eMMC chips to accomplish this? Or is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

I'm using SAMA5D27-WlSOM1 from Microchip.

Comment: There's some open source software like GParted and FDisk that can allow you to create partitions for the eMMC. For booting, U-Boot is probably your safest bet to be able to boot from the partitions.